# How to optimize react animations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, scaling, requestanimationframe

I'm building an interactive map, and on this map there are multiple car routes which can be spawned by a user by selection from a menu. Each car route is an *animation* of a car moving along a route.

The app works fine, however, there are a couple of hundred animations that the user can choose to spawn, and the idea is that all the animations selected should run at the same time.

Each animation is defined by a function that looks as so...

```
var animate = function(current) {

    // If animation has not reached limit yet,
    // call the next frame.
    if (counter <= limit) {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }

    // Do things every second.
    if (current >= (last + 1000)) {

      counter += 1; 

      // Do stuff.

    }
}
```

Whenever an animation is called, this function is called and added to the event-loop. Based on the code above, the car should appear to be moving every second. This works as intended, however, if the user were to decide to spawn 100 animations, then 100 instances of this function will run in the background and slow down the code significantly.

My question is, what are some front-end optimization techniques that might come in handy to help speed up my animations. One optimization I made was to switch from `setInterval` to `requestAnimationFrame`, but I'm not sure how much this really improved anything.

What other techniques might help? Are there any concurrency or threading techniques that might help if I had 100 instances of `animate()` running? I'm not sure what the approach is for front-end applications.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use library react-pose with animation

`Document`: https://popmotion.io/pose/

`Example`: https://o46l299mkq.codesandbox.io/

`Good post`: https://medium.com/@joomiguelcunha/amazing-react-animation-with-react-pose-3b67d9eb6e07